# Porting MFC to Win32SDK Application

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, porting

I have 2 Application one in Win32SDK an Other one in MFC.

What should be my approach to port code on either side with minimum complication.

Comment: You want to port what to what? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm puzzled, both apps already run on Windows don't they?  MFC is just a class library that wraps Win32.  Porting typically means cross-platform.  I think you need to add more detail about the scope of each application, and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Approach 1 : MFC -> Win32API(Main Project)   OR Approach 2: Win32SDK -> MFC(Main Project)

Comment: I even have some COM code in win32SDK project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to port to MFC rather than from MFC. Simply because MFC wraps up a lot of functionality that you'll have to reimplement if you remove it. A lot of this depends on the nature and size of the projects involved and also the skills and experience of the developer(s) that will be doing it.

Can you give more details?

Comment: what will happen if i have some UI window in my SDK Code.. I tried to embed my SDK code in MFC and removed windows.h because mfc throws some error saying "windows file should not be included in mfc".I even have some COM code in win32SDK project

Comment: You can mix MFC code and Win32 API windows with no problem - just careful if they need to interoperate. If your COM produces a DLL/OCX, you can create an MFC wrapper with a wizard.

Comment: so Win32SDK code to MFC Project it is Thanks :) for making decision of porting.